# Converting venue or address taken to a geo point library for android

Tags: android, location

I want to allow users to post pictures already stored on their phone and then allow them to type up the address where the picture was taken. Is it possible to then convert that address to a geo point using some android or third party library or do I go about implementing such? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes both geocoding and reverse geocoding are possible and you can use the Google Play Services. A very good tutorial on the developers.android website can be found at the following link: http://developer.android.com/training/location/display-address.html